# mysql how to allow user to update a column in a DB once with php

Tags: php, mysql

So I have two different tables, a users table and an articles table. The idea is to allow a user to rate an article, but only allow them to rate it once (possible change their existing rating too but I can come to that conclusion later).

As of now I just have the update value working to allow them to rate the article, but of course a user can rate an article as many times as they want.

To give you an idea of how I have everything working, when a user logins in, a session is created with their user information. So when they go to rate an article, I have the ability to check the user, I just don't know how to stop them from rating if they have already rated a specific article.

The user table consists of among other things their username and their unique ID

and the article table consists among other things the article contents, the article unique ID, and the articles rating.

I had some really sloppy ideas like when the user rates an article their ID gets stored into the articles row in some kind of "users who have rated" column, and then I can do a for loop or something to siphon out all the user IDs and then check if their ID exists in that articles entry but then each article would have a row with possibly hundreds or thousands of userIDs on it and there seems like there would be a more elegant way.

Any help or direction is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `UserRatings` table which has foreign keys to the users table and the articles table, and stores a row linking the user to the article, and the rating they gave it and when it occurred.

Then if a user tried to rate it again you just check this table for the user ID/article ID combination before allowing it.

And then if you wanted got can do things like show the user a list of articles they have previously rated, etc

Comment: Thank! I implemented this method. Works well!